# Where is !~ documented?

Tags: ruby, regex, operators

Where is Ruby's `!~` documented? I expected it on the [Regexp page](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Regexp.html) or the [String page](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/String.html) but it's not there. While `=~` appears 49 times on the Regexp page and 8 times on the String page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Object.html#method-i-method) to find a method's owner:

```
''.method(:!~)
#=> #<Method: String(Kernel)#!~>

//.method(:!~)
#=> #<Method: Regexp(Kernel)#!~>
```

`!~` was defined in the `Kernel` module, which is included by `Object`:

```
String.ancestors
#=> [String, Comparable, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]

Regexp.ancestors
#=> [Regexp, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

And because `Kernel` is included in (every) `Object`, its instance methods are documented in [`Object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Object.html) for convenience. (or "clarity" as the documentation says, but IMO that makes it less clear)

So here it is: [`Object#!~`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Object.html#method-i-21-7E)

> #### obj !~ other → true or false
>
> Returns `true` if two objects do not match (using the `=~` method), otherwise `false`.

Comment: Thanks for all those infos, that's been quite helpful for fishing other methods I wondered about later.

Answer (score 2):

It’s [on `Object`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Object.html#method-i-21-7E), because it can just delegate to any `=~` implementation.

Comment: In fact, `Object` (or more precisely `Kernel`) also implements the default `=~`, which is overridden by `Regexp`, `String` and `Symbol`.